# Turning Off Autocomplete for "password" input fields in Chrome

Tags: autocomplete

How can I turn Off Autocomplete for *password* input fields in a html form.

- `autocomplete="false"`

or

- `autocomplete="off"`.

Comment: By autocomplete you actually mean the password manager here? Why would you try and disable that? Whether to use the password manager is a decision you should leave up to the user.

Comment: @CBroe not if you you are the employer, I can see good reason why you would forbid a browser to save the passwords of employees.

Comment: @KamiKaze well then that should be implemented on a network policy level or something like that. But as a general “well it will increase security” argument I think this is completely bogus. On the contrary, my password manager is an added step in protecting me from phishing sites - because when I am on a page that _looks_ like my online banking page, but the password manager does _not_ suggest me the login data I used earlier, that is a sign to pay attention and check what site I am actually on …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser first fill username than fill password.This code worked for me :D

```
$('#gsmloginnum').on('input', function() {
        $('#gsmPassword').prop("readonly", true);
        $( "#gsmPassword").css("border-color", "#fff");
    });

 $( "#gsmPassword" ).focus(function() {
        $( "#gsmPassword").removeAttr("readonly");

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

to hide your saved password or any text input that is saved make your input "readonly" and change "onfocus" like this.

```html
<input readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" autocomplete="off" type="password">
```